# Prolog script with test on Unix

Tags: unix, prolog, test-suite

I have a prolog script and runs without any problems on Windows with swi-prolog,
but when I run the script on Linux there is a error related to test suite:

```
ERROR: /home/test_suite.pl:12:
catch/3: Undefined procedure: begin_tests/1
```

Where

```
:- begin_tests(reason).
```

indicates the beginning of test set in file test_suite.pl. 
If I run the script excluding test_suite.pl file then the script runs without any problems.

### Have no idea why Unix does not understand begin (begin_tests/1) and end (end_tests/1) of the test?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd be amazed at how much easier it is to answer this question if we can look at the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the testing library installed on your pc?  plunit does not come bundled with swi-prolog.  Try the instructions here- http://onek.posterous.com/how-to-build-plunit

If that is installed, did you include the testing library?

Comment: and, O.P., are you using swi-prolog on unix, or some other prolog AND the same version? Good luck.

Comment: To clarify things, I am using swi-prolog on Ubuntu 9.10. 
I copied from windows and imported library plunit but there was another problem related to another undefined procedure, which was mentioned in @DaveEdelstein 's link:

ERROR: plunit:set_test_flag/2: Undefined procedure: plunit:create_prolog_flag/3

and on the sma elink there was a solution to upgrade swi-prolog to version 5.10, so I upgraded the whole system to 12.04 and prolog was updated too (unfortunately, upgrading or reinstalling only prolog did not upgrade the version).
-
Thanks for help!